# Add spaces before Capital Letters then turn them to lowercase string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that caps space in which it takes input like "iLikeSwimming" then it outputs "i like swimming".

This is my try:

```
function isUpper(str) {
    return !/[a-z]/.test(str) && /[A-Z]/.test(str);
}

function capSpace(txt) {
  var arr = Array.from(txt);
  for (let i = 1; i < txt.length; i++){
    if (isUpper(txt[i]) == true) {
        arr.splice((i),0,' ')
    }
  }
  return arr.join('').toString().toLowerCase();
}
```

It's good for strings with only one capital letter, however, it gets kind of weird with more than one.

Example Input and outputs:
Inputs:
`capSpace("iLikeSwimming"); capSpace("helloWorld");`
Outputs:
`'i lik eswimming' 'hello world'`

I'd really appreciate it if someone can point the issue with my code. I know there are other questions "similar" to this, but I'm trying to learn my mistake rather than just copying, I couldn't make sense of any of the other questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why it gets weird with strings that have more than 1 capital letter is that every time you find one, you add a *blank space* which makes the following indices **increase** in a single unit.

It's a simple workaround: just place a counter `splitCount` to keep track of how many spaces you've added and sum it with the index `i` to correct the indices.

```js
function isUpper(str) {
    return !/[a-z]/.test(str) && /[A-Z]/.test(str);
}

function capSpace(txt) {
  var arr = Array.from(txt);
  var splitCount = 0; // added a counter
  for (let i = 1; i < txt.length; i++){
    if (isUpper(txt[i]) === true) {
        // sum it with i
        arr.splice((i + splitCount),0,' ')
        splitCount++; // increase every time you split
    }
  }
  return arr.join('').toString().toLowerCase();
}
console.log(capSpace('iLikeSwimming'))
```

Answer (score 5):

**1)** You can simply achieve this using regex and string [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method

```js
const capSpace = (str) => str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, (match) => ` ${match.toLowerCase()}`);

console.log(capSpace("iLikeSwimming"));
console.log(capSpace("helloWorld"));
```

**2)** You can also do with [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#:%7E:text=prototype.-,join(),returned%20without%20using%20the%20separator.)

```js
const capSpace = (str) =>
  str
  .split("")
  .map((s) => (/[A-Z]/.test(s) ? ` ${s.toLowerCase()}` : s))
  .join("");

console.log(capSpace("iLikeSwimming"));
console.log(capSpace("helloWorld"));
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know you could pass in a function as the second parameter of replace.

Comment: This is an elegant solution, iLikeIt!

Comment: Wow! You really took my long weird code and made it way nicer! Thank you for opening my eyes to this :)!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple one I made. Matches capital letters then replaces them.

```js
const testString = "ILoveMoney";

function caps2Spaces(str) {
  const matches = str.match(/[A-Z]/g);
  for (const letter of matches) {
    str = str.replace(letter, ` ${letter.toLowerCase()}`)
  }
  return str.trim();
}
console.log(caps2Spaces(testString));
```